# how to extend my root (/) partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I am trying to extend my root partition (sda7) with (sda9). I am trying to increase the size for my root drive and found that most issues with others have an extended part while mine seems to be a standalone partition itself.
Another issue is when creating new partitions, it seems to also create "unallocated" partitions. I would actually like to merge these unallocated together.

[image: attached gparted image]

Comment: Don't. Those unallocated portions are for better alignment. What's in `sda9`? If it can be removed just do it and then move `sda7` all the way to the left so you can finally resize it.

Comment: sda9 is empty. i just wanted to add more space to sda7(root) because it is running out of space. i intend to upgrade from version 14 LTS to version 16 but have yet to do that due to lack of space.

Comment: If so you already have the answer above.

Comment: You should consider shrinking sda5 to make more room for resizing your sda7. If you need specifics on how to do this, please ask.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so to do that you need to :

- Delete sda9 (right click Delete)
- Move sda7 to the left, and resize it  (right click Resize/Move)

You should do that using a live Ubuntu (or other) because sda7 needs to be unmounted to do that.

Comment: Move left, resize right... very good! You're the first person who I've seen that got it right! You need to add just a few more specifics, like... boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB... start `gparted`... tell how to move... etc. This way, future viewers can read your **complete** solution.